# Stop bots from crawling my Google App Engine website

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I've noticed my Google App Engine site is being crawled by a lot of bots (such as Baido and Ahrefs), and they're eating all of my bandwidth and datastore read ops.

I know on just a regular self-hosted site I'd put a robots.txt in my base folder, but how exactly do I tell bots not to crawl my site on Google App Engine? I'm running python and jinja 2 if that makes a difference.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do this in your `app.yaml`

```
- url: /robots.txt
  static_files: static/robots.txt
  upload: static/robots.txt
```

Then, as long as you have `static/robots.txt` in your project, you're good to go.

Comment: Thanks. Just to add (because this went wrong for me), this has to be above the `- url: /.*` because otherwise it's skipped over.

Comment: Dot (".") needs to be escaped with a backslash in "url" and "upload" because they are regular expressions ("- url: /robots\.txt
  static_files: static/robots.txt
  upload: static/robots\.txt")

Comment: Technically, that's correct. And yet it is so unlikely to cause an issue in this case. On balance here, I go with clarity over precision.

Comment: Will this stop crawlers from spinning up my public but rarely visited wordpress site hosted on GAE?

Comment: It might stop the well-behaved ones, but crawler's gonna crawl.